# How to walk through array of Struct in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a program which creates an array or struct and go through it for processing. Initially it initialize the array with the defined nyumber of elements. Then for some number of element in array, the name is assigned.

I pretend the code that is equal to my scenario which is tested in codebloc and get the similar error. The problem is described in comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _car {
    char *name;
    int year;
} Car;

char *getCarName(char *name, int var);
void processCar();
void printCars(Car car[]);
int INCREMENT = 10;

int main(void)
{
    processCar();
    return 0;
}

void processCar()
{
    // create car array with amount of INCREMENT
    Car CAR_ARRAY[INCREMENT];
    int a=0;
    // This function assign name for Car amount 10 less than INCREMENT
    while (a<INCREMENT - 2) {
        char *carName;
        carName = getCarName(&carName, a);

        CAR_ARRAY[a].name = malloc(strlen(carName) + 1);
        strcpy(CAR_ARRAY[a].name, carName);
        a++;
    }

     printCars(CAR_ARRAY);
}

void printCars(Car car[])
{
    printf("IN Car \n");
    int a = 0;
    // when try to call name for car amount equals to INCREMENT program terminates.
    while(a<INCREMENT) {
        if (car[a].name != NULL) // checking if NULL
            printf("Car Name : %d -> %s\n", a, car[a].name);
        a++;
    }
}

char *getCarName(char *name, int var)
{
    name = "Toyota";
    return name;
}
```

What is the right way to check the struct value on struct array whether it can be called?

**EDIT**

I created a hack to do this as follows.

```
// added these right after creating array
for (a = 0; a < INCREMENT; a++)
    CAR_ARRAY[a].name = NULL;
```

I dont know if it is a standard way or not. pls advice.

Comment: Is your *first* problem that this code won't even *compile* (because it won't on my rig with warnings pedantic; you're passing a `char**` as a `char*` parameter).

Comment: its running on my codeblocks IDE 13.2 with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`

Comment: Not commenting on the code itself (and believe it, it isn't easy), your fault is coming from invoking undefined behavior. Your `processCar()` is only populating INCREMENT-2 names, yet you're printing INCREMENT names, the last two are not populated and thus invoking UB on access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for `NULL` before printing, which is a good idea, but it doesn't help you here, because your last two cars are uninitialised and likely contain garbage: The `name` pointer is not `NULL`, but doesn't point to a valid address either. Segmentation violation ensues.

You should initialise all cars, not only `INCREMENT - 2`. Alternatively, you could initialise your cars to zero by calling `memset` before your initialisation:

```
memset(CAR_ARRAY, 0, sizeof(Car) * INCREMENT);
```

As an aside, the way you deal with `getCarName` is rather shaky as well. At the moment, your name is a pointer to a string literal. Your local variable `carName` does a half-hearted double duty: You try to pass it by reference (but essentially you don't) and you also return it.

Basically, you could do this in one of two ways. The easier one here is to return a pointer. in that case, you don't have to pass any string:

```
char *getCarName(int var)
{
    static char *names[3] = {"Toyota", "Dodge", "Peugeot"};
    return names[var % 3];
}
```

and call it like so:

```
char *carName = getCarName(&carName, a);
```

Alternatively, you could pass a `char` pointer by reference, i.e. as pointer to pointer to char. In that case, you don't have to return anything:

```
void getCarName(char **name, int var)
{
    static char* names[3] = {"Toyota", "Dodge", "Peugeot"};
    *name = names[var % 3];
}
```

Call it like so:

```
char *carName;
getCarName(&carName, a);
```

There are other scenarios here, for example if you just pass a char pointer and have `getCarName` fill it, but I'll leave that for now - it would make everything even more complicated.

Comment: wow.. cool man, it is doing the right job. and one question. Do i need to free it up once used?

Comment: "The name pointer is not NULL" - it can be, especially on debug builds on some compilers. it's UB.

Comment: @M Oehm: Indeed he is checking `car[a].name != NULL` which is good, so the ONLY way I see this is crashing is because `car[a].name` contains some random memory address (because only INCREMENT-2 elements were initialized) - and printing it crashes. That's the catch right?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Of course one of the possibilities is that the pointer is NULL. The pointer is not NULL in this case, however, otherwise the condition would have caught it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But technically even comparing an uninitialized value against NULL is UB.

Comment: @BlueBird: No. Setting memory with `memset` is independent from allocating it on the heap, although `malloc` and ´memset` are a frequent combination of system calls. The memory in your case sits on the stack and should not be freed. (It would be a rather bad idea, really.)

Comment: @dmcr_code: Yes. The code does some error checking, which is good. But the error checking relies on an invariant: Either the `name` field of a structure points to a valid character string in memory or it is `NULL`. The uninitialised car structures might violate that invariant. By zeroing out the memory, you lay the foundation to proper error checking by ensuring that cars that don't have a name at least have `NULL` as their name field.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:  "But technically even comparing an uninitialized value against NULL is UB" --> I don't think this is right. This check `car[a].name != NULL` is fine, the problem is what happens afterwards I believe ...

Comment: @dmcr_code: that's what happens in *practice* (but with the advance of the compilers, who knows what will in the future). I said: *technically*. read this, if you don't know the difference: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Comment: @MOehm in your codes above, you have done this.. 
`static const *names[3] = {"Toyota", "Dodge", "Peugeot"};
    *name = name[var % 3];`
you are assigning to `*name` from value `name[var % 3]` should it be `names[var%3]` or is it correct. and i dont understand how it works. can you explain it pls.

Comment: @BlueBird: Oops, you're right, good catch. The example just expands your "Toyota" example so that it uses the passed `var`. It cycles through the three car brands. The modulo operator brings `var` to the valid range of 0 to 2. I'll fix that.

Comment: @MOehm you mean it is working like fetching the index? right?

Comment: @MOehm: I guess he'd still have to free this: `malloc(strlen(carName)`

Comment: @MOehm btw, why do you use static key word for `static char *names[3]` in the function `char *getCarName(int var)`